# confusion of conditional constructions

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions, will-would, conditionals

> Am I crazy? If I am, **would** I realize it?

Why can't I use will here? I think it is in first conditional form. So will should be used

Answer (score 1):

If you were to substitute *will* here, you would change the meaning of your question to involve the future.  Your question becomes one of determining the fact at some unknown future time.

A more standard way of phrasing in the present tense would be either

> Am I crazy?  If I *were*, would I realize it?

or more colloquially

> Am I crazy?  If I *were*, how would I know?

Note the use of *were* which in this case is about conditionality, not about past tense.

Comment: So can we use, " If I am" instead of "If I were"

Comment: It is not correct to use "am" in the conditional clause, but everyone would understand what you are trying to express.

Answer (score 1):

## What you need here is called the subjunctive mood and the conditional.

First, you are expressing a hypothetical, so you should use the conditional form "would" instead of "will".

Second, you have an error previously in your second sentence by using the word "am" in "If I am", it should be if I were, this is called the subjunctive mood, which is used when expressing a non factual conditional.